# Showing Picture with Advanced Custom fields /fishpig extension

Tags: wordpress, magento, fishpig

Using advanced custom fields with fishpig extension just shows URL or “Array” or “ID” of the picture in fronted.
How can the picture be shown.

Answer (score 1):

When creating a field of Image type, you can choose the return type. If you are using the latest version of the [FishPig Advanced Custom Fields](http://fishpig.co.uk/magento/wordpress-integration/advanced-custom-fields/) add-on extension (1.4.0.1), you have 3 options for the return type:

- Object
- URL
- Array

If you choose object, the image model will be returned. Once you have the image model you can get any of the different URLs for the image (each URL is for a different sized image). For a list of methods you can call to get different images, see [this article](http://fishpig.co.uk/magento/wordpress-integration/post-images/).

If you choose URL, the URL to the originally uploaded image will be returned.

If you choose array, an array will be returned that contains the image ID, URL and object. (eg. $image['id'], $image['object'] and $image['url']). To convert the image ID to an object, use the following code:

```
<?php $image = Mage::getModel('wordpress/image')->load($image['id']) ?>
<?php if ($image->getId()): ?>
    <img src="<?php echo $image->getAvailableImage() ?>" alt="" />
<?php endif; ?>
```

If you aren't already, I would recommend upgrading [Magento WordPress Integration](http://fishpig.co.uk/magento/wordpress-integration/) and [Advanced Custom Fields](http://fishpig.co.uk/magento/wordpress-integration/advanced-custom-fields/) to the latest versions.

Answer (score 0):

when echoing out the URL, run this inside an img src.

i.e.

```
<img src="<?php echo the_field('image-url') ?>" />
```

Comment: could you please elaborate what about you using fishpig extension ?

Comment: For a developer this may clear things, but I don´t know how to put this together. Think of me like an programming idiot. I just want to fill my post with some text and pictures between that text. Is it possible to use repeater fields, which will print out content (picture to text) if available.

Comment: Hi @Bingo, please look Ben Tideswell's answer, that explains the usage of this and is a far better representation of what mine is.